# jQuery wrap chaining

Tags: jquery, html, chaining

```html
<p>hello</p>
```

```javascript
$("p").wrap("<div class='inner'></div>").wrap("<div class='outer'></div>");
```

The result is `<div class="inner"><div class="outer"><p>hello</p></div></div>`,

Why is it so? I expected **inner** inside **outer**, not otherwise.

Here is fiddle to play with : http://jsfiddle.net/qnYDY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `wrap()` method:

> ...returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 3):

I think the first wrap call returns "p" itself , so when you wrap it again, the "outer" div will wrap the "p" tag and not any of its parents.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Jamie Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19620295/1183010) `wrap()` returns *the original set of arguments*.

You could use `parent()` to append to the newly added element:

```
$("p").wrap("<div class='inner'></div>").parent().wrap("<div class='outer'></div>");
```